# Adding a ToolTip to an OvalShape in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, tooltip, powerpack

I'm trying to add a tooltip to an `OvalShape` (`Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks.OvalShape`).  Since its not a `Control`, I can't use the simple `SetToolTip()` method in the `ToolTip` class.  How might I go about showing a `ToolTip` on an `OvalShape`?  I don't absolutely have to use the `ToolTip` class if anyone has any better ideas.  I'd also like to keep the `OvalShape`, unless anyone has a better solution that can give me inheritence from `Control` while keeping a nice circular shape.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to take advantage of the MouseHover event you can get out of the control.  This worked well enough:

```
    bool hoverSeen = false;

    private void ovalShape1_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        if (!hoverSeen) {
            hoverSeen = true;
            // Todo, fix position
            Point pos = ovalShape1.Parent.PointToClient(Cursor.Position);
            toolTip1.Show("On oval", ovalShape1.Parent, pos);
        }
    }

    private void ovalShape1_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        if (hoverSeen) toolTip1.Hide(ovalShape1.Parent);
        hoverSeen = false;
    }
```